# Allow RDP to public webserver?

Tags: security, remote-desktop, rdp

Is it a huge security flaw to allow user to connect to your server via Remote Desktop? Right now i have a setup where i only allow a couple of ip-addresses to connect via the RDP port but i am thinking of removing this and allow all IP's to connect so i can RDP with my iPhone if there is some problem when I'm not at home.

So as long as i have a secure password do you guys think this is a bad idea? Is there anything else i can do to make it a bit more secure but still be able to connect from "wherever"? Is it for example possible to setup a page that i must visit that "allow anyone to login for 2 hours". Some kind of security by obscurity thingy?

Thankful for any help i can get.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should post this question to serverfault. But anyway.

If you are using only user/password as the access method. Then it will be very easy for an attacker to lock your user ( or all users, thay don't even have to have terminal access rights ). So yes, it will be a huge security flaw. There are lots of way to protect from this treat and make rdp available from wherever. But I am not familiar with any of them.

Answer (score 0):

It's very common to implement two-factor authentication for any remote access to corporate servers. In many companies you'll see the RSA tokens used as a second factor, albeit I prefer to use SMS --- it doesn't matter as long as you have two factors in play: something you know, something you have, something you are.

If your company doesn't want to implement a second factor then I still wouldn't recommend a publicly exposed RDP interface. It's open to brute force attacks, OS exploits or just plain old Denial of Service (if I blast your public interface with traffic then it will slow down legitimate machine use within your company). At a minimum I would look into tunneling over SSH, maybe with a client-side certificate authentication, or I would implement port knocking to get at the server interface in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It is a security flaw, but not so huge. Traffic is encrypted and reading user or password from it is not immediate as in text based protocols as in say ftp. It is just a little bit less secure than ssh.

It obviously has the same flaws as any other remote access (possible brute force or DOS attack). You should also use non a default account name to avoid simplifying task for attackers.

Your idea of opening access only after visiting some page is not bad either. Looks like it's a variant of the classical [port knocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking) mechanism (but beware avoid opening a bigger hole).